# Tener 2 estilos distintos en el mismo th

Tags: html, css

Tengo una tabla en la que quiero poner un texto en blanco y otro en azul, dentro del mismo th.

Pensando y probando cosas, no funcionaba ninguna como quería. Este es mi código

```css
body {
 color: #FF0000;
 font: 14px Sans-Serif;
 padding: 50px;
 background: #eee;
}

#container {
 box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 position: relative;
 background: white; 
}

table {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 15px 0;
}

th {
 background-color: #FF0000 ;
 color: #FFF;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 5px 10px;
}

th small {
 font-size: 9px; 
 color: black;
}

td, th {
 text-align: left;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}
/*
Cambia color de letra
*/
td a {
 color: black;
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 font-size: 16px;
}
th a {
 padding-left: 0;
 color: #FFE800;
}

td:first-of-type a {
 background: url(./.images/file.png) no-repeat 10px 50%;
 padding-left: 35px;
}
th:first-of-type {
 padding-left: 35px;
}

td:not(:first-of-type) a {
 background-image: none !important;
} 

tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

tr:hover td {
 background-color:#DF2727;
}

tr:hover td a {
 color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <title>582100450 (CB_ASFAD_U)</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./.style.css">
   <script src="./.sorttable.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
 <table class="sortable">
     <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Nombre Fichero <br> (Filename) </th>
   <th>Tipo <br> (Type) </th>
   <th>Tamaño <br> (Size) </th>
   <th>Fecha de modificación <br> (Modification date) </th>
  </tr>
  
     </thead>
 </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Probé con un `<p>`, pero no salía muy bien. No sé si es posible hacer esto, pero mi plan es que salga el texto en español en blanco (como está) y el texto en inglés en azul, quedando el mismo estilo de letra, posición y todo eso que tiene actualmente

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para este tipo de cosas es para lo que fue pensada la etiqueta `<span>`. Al no ser un elemento de bloque, no afecta al resto del contenido, por lo que puede ser usado para dar un tamaño diferente, color, grosor... a parte de un elemento.

```css
body {
 color: #FF0000;
 font: 14px Sans-Serif;
 padding: 50px;
 background: #eee;
}

#container {
 box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 position: relative;
 background: white; 
}

table {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 15px 0;
}

th {
 background-color: #FF0000 ;
 color: #FFF;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 5px 10px;
}

th small {
 font-size: 9px; 
 color: black;
}

td, th {
 text-align: left;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}
/*
Cambia color de letra
*/
td a {
 color: black;
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 font-size: 16px;
}
th a {
 padding-left: 0;
 color: #FFE800;
}

td:first-of-type a {
 background: url(./.images/file.png) no-repeat 10px 50%;
 padding-left: 35px;
}
th:first-of-type {
 padding-left: 35px;
}

td:not(:first-of-type) a {
 background-image: none !important;
} 

tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

tr:hover td {
 background-color:#DF2727;
}

tr:hover td a {
 color: #FFF;
}

.ingles {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <title>582100450 (CB_ASFAD_U)</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./.style.css">
   <script src="./.sorttable.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
 <table class="sortable">
     <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Nombre Fichero <br> <span class="ingles"> (Filename) </span></th>
   <th>Tipo <br><span class="ingles"> (Type) </span></th>
   <th>Tamaño <br><span class="ingles"> (Size) </span></th>
   <th>Fecha de modificación <br><span class="ingles"> (Modification date) </span></th>
  </tr>
  
     </thead>
 </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Correcto, lo estaba probando yo ahora y había adoptado la misma solución

Comment: ¡Justo! No se me había ocurrido usar esa etiqueta y mira que la usé algunas veces... ¡Muchas gracias!